# Ошибка undefined reference при компиляции Dev-c++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Добрый день! Пишу простой класс на C++ при компиляции наткнулся на вот такую вот странную проблему.. Я мало что разбираю в C++, но вот мой `.h` и `.cpp` файлы:

> Если есть ошибки в правописании кода, прошу оставлять на будущее заметки типа: так нельзя писать в C++, а надо вот так...

***Student.cpp***

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>
using std::string;

Student::Student(){}

void Student::setName(string n){
    name = n;
}
void Student::setSurname(string s){
    surname = s;
}
void Student::setAge(int a){
    age = a;
}
void Student::setCourse(int c) {
    course = c;
}
void Student::setGroup(string g){
    group = g;
}
void Student::setMarks(string* mark){
    marks = mark;
}
string Student::getName(){
    return name;
}
string Student::getSurname(){
    return surname;
}
int Student::getAge(){
    return age;
}
int Student::getCourse(){
    return course;
}
string Student::getGroup(){
    return group;
}
string* Student::getMarks(){
    return marks;
}
```

***Student.h***

```
#ifndef Student_h
#define Student_h
#include <string>
using std::string;
class Student{

    public:
        Student();
        void setName(string);
        string getName();
        void setSurname(string);
        string getSurname();
        void setAge(int);
        int getAge();
        void setCourse(int);
        int getCourse();
        void setGroup(string);
        string getGroup();
        void setMarks(string*);
        string* getMarks();

    private:
        string name;
        string surname;
        int age;
        int course;
        string group;
        string* marks;
};
#endif
```

***Main.cpp***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(){
    Student test;
    string marks[] = {"B","B","C","A","A","A"};
    test.setName("Name");
    test.setSurname("Surname");
    test.setAge(100);
    test.setCourse(100);
    test.setGroup("606.4");
    test.setMarks(marks);

    cout << test.getName() << endl;
    cout << test.getSurname() << endl;
    cout << test.getAge() << endl;
    cout << test.getCourse() << endl;
    cout << test.getGroup() << endl;
    string* mark = test.getMarks();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
        cout << mark[i] <<" ";
    }
}
```

Вроде все правильно делаю, но странная ошибка при компиляции происходит...

Это при компиляции **`Main.cpp`**

[image: Это при компиляции Main метода]

А это при компиляции **`Student.cpp`**

[image: Компиляция Student]

Подскажите где все мои грубые ошибки?

Comment: Ошибка линковщика. Похоже, компилируется только файл `main.cpp`, но не `student.cpp`. Точно ли добавлен в проект файл `student.cpp`?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT   Похоже, что вместо проекта консольного приложения вы создаете Windows приложение.  К тому же объектный модуль с определениями класса Student не подключен к проекту, а потому все определения, находящиеся в нем недоступны.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Значит мне нужно это все в проекте строить? Я в одной папке все это сделал и пытался запустить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насчет того, почему не компилируется - как уже писали, ваши ошибки - ошибки линковки, так что это неподключенный к проекту файл `Student.cpp`, а ненайденная `WinMain` говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь создавать оконное приложение, а не консольное.

Но у вас есть и вторая часть вопроса - как писать. У вас нет ошибок - в том смысле, что они вызовут неработоспособность программы. Но, примерно как вы и сформулировали - так писать на C++ не стоит...

Я бы начал с того, что у вас по сути не класс, а структура. В том смысле, что ваш класс не содержит какого-то специфичного внутреннего состояния, которое следовало бы обязательно поддерживать в согласованном состоянии, или какой-то иной функциональности, кроме установки и возврата полей. Поэтому лично я не вижу большого греха в том, чтобы просто объявить ваш класс структурой (т.е. классом со всеми открытыми членами) и работать прямо с ними:

```
struct Student{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
    int course;
    string group;
    string* marks;
};
...
Student test;
test.name = "Name";
```

Если же планируется какая-то более серьезная работа, или по заданию требуется, чтобы это был класс - то лучше такие мелкие однострочные функции делать inline (встраиваемыми), т.е. определять их прямо в объявлении класса. Это позволит компилятору не вызывать их, а просто встраивать в код, что благотворно сказывается на производительности. И еще - я бы делал все функции возврата константными - чтобы их можно было вызывать и для константных объектов. Строки я бы передавал как константные ссылки, чтобы поменьше копировать.

```
class Student{
  public:
    Student();
    void   setName(const string& s)    { name = s; }
    string getName() const             { return name; }
    void   setSurname(const string& s) { surname = s; }
    string getSurname() const          { return surname; }

    ...
  private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
    int course;
    string group;
    string* marks;
};
```

Еще - оценки у вас явно односимвольные, так что я бы не городил массив строк, а использовал просто строку - которая, в общем-то, и есть массив символов (при этом я бы дописал функцию *добавления оценки* - т.е. присоединения к этой строке очередного символа). Кроме того, вы бы избавились и от того, что именуют "волшебными константами" - вам не надо было бы при выводе помнить, что оценок 6:

```
for(char c : mark){
    cout << c <<" ";
}
```

И еще - все строки вы в класс *копируете*, что правильно - объект получается самодостаточен, "все свое ношу с собой". А вот этот массив вы просто передаете как указатель на *внешнюю* по отношению к классу сущность. и если поменяется она - поменяется, получается, и состояние класса. Грубо говоря, зачетка вашего студента - не зачетка, а обложка с бумажкой, на которой написано - "а оценки мои записаны вон там, на классной доске" - где их сможет подправить любой хулиган... Т.е. если даже вы работаете с массивом строк - его лучше скопировать внутрь, для пущей инкапсуляции.

И еще - почему бы вам не создать еще один конструктор, который бы создавал сразу именованного студента? Вряд ли имя и фамилия будут меняться (разве что студентка замуж выйдет :)).

Comment: Хмм, ответ супер, да, на счет структуры я с вами согласен, но мне по заданию дали создать класс... На счет оценок я не особо понял, можно тут по подробнее?

Comment: Заведите `string marks;` и функции типа `setMarks(сщтые string& m)`, как и для других строк, и `Student::addMark(char m) { marks += m; }`. Тогда назначить оценки можно или как `test.setMarks("ABBCAB")`, или как `test.addMark('A'); test.addMark('B'); ...`

Comment: Ааа понял :)) Сейчас я все проверю и постараюсь сделать)

Comment: Функцию setMark где мне писать? В Student.cpp, header файле или в Main'e ?

Comment: Это член Student, а уж где напишете - дело ваше :)

Comment: Я просто особо не разбираюсь в c++, поэтому спрашиваю) :) Спасибо большое, все работает все отлично)